# Opencart Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, vpn

I have an opencart system that was running on a smaller server. When I moved it to a Godaddy VPN and tried to load it up it's giving me this error.

```
Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in
/home/livinghebrew1/public_html/shopping_cart/system/library/db/mysqli.php
on line 7
```

Here's the code it's referring to.

```
line 6 - public function __construct($hostname, $username, $password, $database, $port = '3306') {

line 7 -    $this->link = new \mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database, $port );
```

Comment: Do you have that module installed? As always, check `php_info()`.

Comment: I apologize in advance for asking elementary questions. Where would I check that?

Comment: You can always debug your configuration with the [`phpinfo()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php).

Comment: load it up: http://i.imgur.com/TWQarQ6.jpg